# RegEx to extract the first 6 to 10 digit number, excluding 8 digit numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have the below test file names:

```
abc001_20111104_summary_123.txt
abc008_200700953_timeline.txt
abc008_20080402_summary200201573unitf.txt
123456.txt
100101-100102 test.txt
abc008_20110902_summary200110254.txt
abcd 200601141 summary.txt
abc008_summary_200502169_xyz.txt
```

I need to extract **a number** from each file name.

The number must be **6, 7, 9 or 10 digits** long (so, **excluding 8-digit** numbers).

I want to get **the first number**, if more than one is found, or empty string if none is found.

I managed to do this in a **2 steps process**, first removing the 8-digit numbers, then extracting the 6 to 10 digits numbers from my list.

```
step 1 
  regex:  ([^0-9])([0-9]{8})([^0-9])
  replacement:  \1\3

step 2
  regex: (.*?)([1-9]([0-9]{5,6}|[0-9]{8,9}))([^0-9].*)
  replacement:  \2
```

The numbers I get after this 2 steps process are exactly what I'm looking for:

```
[]
[200700953]
[200201573]
[123456]
[100101]
[200110254]
[200601141]
[200502169]
```

Now, the question is:
**Is there a way to do this in a one step process?**

I've seen [this nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899552/regex-to-find-numbers-excluding-four-digit-numbers) to a similar question, however, it gives me the latest number if more than one found.

**Note:** Testing with [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/).

Comment: Specifying your programming language would be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your regex engine supports lookbehind assertions:

```
(?<!\d)\d{6}(?:\d?|\d{3,4})(?!\d)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!\d)   # Assert that the previous character (if any) isn't a digit
\d{6}     # Match 6 digits
(?:       # Either match
 \d?      # 0 or 1 digits
|         # or
 \d{3,4}  # 3 or 4 digits
)         # End of alternation
(?!\d)    # Assert that the next character (if any) isn't a digit
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim! This solves the issue. Thank you for the explanation too. I ended up using an amended version of your solution though, because there were cases when I had to extract a range or a second number, or both, but the part you provided is untouched. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
regex: /(?:^|\D)(\d{6}(?:\d(?:\d{2,3})?)?)(?:\D|$)/
replacement: \1
```

This will extract six digits, optionally followed by one more (7 total), optionally followed by 2 or 3 more (9 or 10).

Answer (score 0):

for every string $subject

```
$subject = "abc001_20111104_summary_123.txt";
$subject ="abc008_200700953_timeline.txt";
$subject ="abc008_20080402_summary200201573unitf.txt";
$subject ="123456.txt"
$subject ="100101-100102 test.txt"
$subject ="abc008_20110902_summary200110254.txt";
$subject ="abcd 200601141 summary.txt";
$subject ="abc008_summary_200502169_xyz.txt";

$pattern = '*(?<!\d)(\d{6,7}|\d{9,10})(?!\d)*';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

You get the expected result:

- empty
- 200700953
- 200201573
- 123456
- 100101
- 200110254
- 200601141
- 200502169

Answer (score 0):

Matching word boundaries or non-number at the edge of `[0-9]{6,7}|[0-9]{9,10}` should do it:

```
([^0-9]|\<)([0-9]{6,7}|[0-9]{9,10})([^0-9]|\>)
```